# Get Permission from android application

Tags: android, permissions, runtime, file-permissions

I am creating one application in android in which i want the user to set permission from my application's setting menu. For example i need permission for read contact from my device so for that if user select allow to read contact from setting menu then it read contact from device. In marshmallow all permission should taken at runtime while below marshmallow permission are define in android manifest. So is it possible to take permission for all version from my application's setting menu.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Yes, I read that document but that is for marshmallow and above version but i need for all versions.And i also don't want to show dialog for asking permission.

Comment: Sure, just wrap all the permissions code in a check for API level.  Pretty standard stuff.

Answer (score 1):

1) Pre-Marshmallow, the user grants app permissions (as stated in the `Manifest`) during installation and there is no way to bypass this behavior. Of course later on you can have your own settings menu with revocable permissions, however, on a system level, permissions granted to your app will not be affected by whatever the user selects there.

2)

> And i also don't want to show dialog for asking permission

You also won't be able to bypass this in Marshmallow. This is a security mechanism aiming to inform the user what permissions the app requests.

Toggling permissions from an app's built-in settings menu is definitely not how the permission system works on Android.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. some how it is useful for me